# why java regex pattern error comes in windows but not in solaris environment

Tags: java, regex, exception

Why does this string problem occur only in windows?

How do I replace the file seperator?
Both of the below methods are not working for me.

The error is:

> java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near
>   index 1.

```
String s ="pathoffile";

if(File.separator.equals("\\"))
   s= s.replaceAll(File.separator,"/");


if(File.separator.equals("\\"))
   s= s.replaceAll("\\","/");
```

Comment: You can also use forward slashes everywhere, the JVM on windows gets it right. Life is easier that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape a backslash in a regular expression *twice*:

```
 s= s.replaceAll("\\\\","/");
```

Once, to put a backslash into a String.

Twice, because regular expressions have special character classes, like `\d`, and those start with a backslash, so a literal backslash is `\\`.

But what you should probably really do is not use a regular expression at all to [just replace single characters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29):

```
s = s.replace('\\', '/');
```

Comment: @sunleo just by seeing your profile, don't forget to mark this post as an answer by clicking on the check next to the text (and do the same for your other questions). There is a wait time of 15 minutes to mark the post as answer.

Comment: sorry am new so i didn't do that now i did that is this ok ? Please help me.

Comment: @sunleo don't worry, we were new once upon a time and learned in the way.